# Which file type is better for importing data into SQL Server: CSV or JSON?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, csv, data-migration

I am taking part in a project where a third-party company will provide us with an export of our customer data so that we can import them into our in-house system.

Each customer record has about twenty fields.  The data-types are strings, booleans, integers and dates (with time components and UTC offset components).  None of the strings are longer than 250 chars.  The integer can range from 0 to 100,000 inclusive.

I have to import about 2 million users into a SQL Server database.  I am in the planning phase and trying to determine if I should ask for the export file in csv or json.  I am planning on asking for both (just in case), but I don't yet know if I can.

If I can only pick one file-type (csv or json), which is better for this kind of work? Can anyone with experience importing data into SQL Server provide any advice on which is better?

Comment: Is disk space or transmission time going to be an issue? I assume you're targeting just one table: what tool do you intend to use for the import?

Comment: I would DEFINITELY ask for some samples of a few thousand records (in both formats, if possible) so you can experiment. From what you say here, depending on the source system the data comes from and how they're exporting it, I'd focus on the date format they use as the most likely source of import problems. Verify you can import it as it comes and don't need to do any transforms.

Comment: All other things being equal, it's easier to grab some problematic lines of a CSV file (with grep or something similar) and read them into a text editor or Excel, than it is to grab a whole JSON document that has one corrupted element.  So if I had to choose just one, I'd pick CSV.

Comment: Define *better*: CSV is flat - just a long list of records of a given shape. JSON can be nested and contain sub-objects and sub-lists/arrays - CSV can't do that. So maybe the real question is: what are you requirements? What kind of data do you need to import?

Comment: @AnnL. it would be into just one table.  For transmission I assume I will just receive the csv or json file in one or more sub-files.  I haven't chosen which tool I will use. I will be using a Windows machine however.  (at)marc_c: the data types I need to import are in the second paragraph

Comment: @marc_s what I meant to say is my data is not hierarchical, so I can use both

Answer (score 1):

The same are fast if you use the bulk method.
From SQL Server 2016 the json is natively supported and you can manipulate it easily with JSON function.
You can also import file directly via T-SQL with OPENJSON
and OPENROWSET BULK IMPORT. Alternately you can put the T-SQL above into SSIS package.

See this article for more details:
https://www.sqlshack.com/import-json-data-into-sql-server/

Comment: I am leaning towards using CSV because according to my research, the entire JSON object would have to be loaded into memory, whereas the CSV file can be processed line by line.  Given that there are roughly 2 million customers with 20 fields each, I think that CSV could be "safer" in this case.

Comment: In my opinion the most important thing is how you get data from DB and how write them into files. You should get them in chunks (for example 10000 records at a time) and write them via batch mode (using bulk insert) and no row-by-row